# Protect MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mean-stack

I've created a MEAN app which has user authentication (user profiles) on the site itself. These profiles are stored in a collection called users - there are 2 other collections as well. The issue I have, is theres no security around mongo so anyone from within my network (instance in AWS) can connect to mongo using (mongo --host #.#.#.#) which then allows them to do whatever they want to my DB. How can I add authentication to the mongo shell but still allow the website to make CRUD operations?

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to grant role based access control to your Database right ?

well you can configure your mongodb for that.
please  have a look at authentication and authorization in mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/